# Number of possible outcomes in Bernoulli Dice Game

Tags: probability, dice, gambling

To illustrate the issue of skewed distributions, we consider a solitary game where:

1. A player rolls one dice, securing a result $i$ ($i$=1,2,..,6)
2. Then selects $i$ dices out of a set of 6 dices and throws them once, obtaining a sum $s_i$

If the sum $s_i$ is:

- $s_i>12$, the player gets one unit payment
- $s_i=12$, it's a tie
- $s_i<12$, the player pays one unit payment

The total number of outcomes is supposedly $6*6^6$
[From Epstein's Book]

My understanding would be that the number of outcomes is $\sum_{1}^{6}{6^k}$ reflecting that for the case with one dice you get $6$ outcomes only. Is the author considering all 6 dices as different outcomes of the first roll (meaning that getting $i=1$ and picking dice 1 or 5 is different)? If so, why is that?

Comment: You are essentially correct, but with your count, the outcomes are not equally likely. The book’s outcomes are a way to make each outcome equally likely. In the books outcome, it is as if you always roll all $6$ dice, even if you only care about the first $i$ dice you roll.

Comment: As I said, you are essentially correct.

Comment: The main take-away of this is that we tend to prefer to work in equiprobable sample spaces since this allows us to use counting techniques to calculate probabilities by using $\Pr(A)=\dfrac{|A|}{|S|}$.  In situations where outcomes are not equally likely to occur, we may *not* calculate in that way and would need to be more careful.

Comment: One could argue that there are in fact only three outcomes... we either win, lose, or tie.  Use whatever sample space is most convenient for calculation while also adequately describing all outcomes you are interested in investigating.  The sample space including only win,lose,tie for instance you will have lost track of what the initial roll was.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It feels obvious now... I won't make this mistake again.
Am I correct to say this is the same logic as say a game where I win only if I flip 2 Heads? This game means that if the first toss is Tail I lose and if it is Head I get to toss a second time.
My naive count gave 3 outcomes (HH,HT,T) and $P(Lose)=2/3$ if I used the formula without weights.
However, you can easily compute the true probability of losing as 3/4 which is the result you get by doing $2*2$ instead of $1+2$.